# Getting list of documents related to a particular user in Google Apps using Admin Account

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-apps, google-docs-api, google-drive-realtime-api

i am creating an app using google apis.i need to access user's documents through google apis using google admin account.In past i can use google docs api like this

for example i am admin of domain iritesh.com and my email address is ritesh@iritesh.com.i logged in using admin account and can retrieve documents in google drive of rajat@iritesh.com using user_id = rajat@iritesh.com.

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/"+user_id+"/private/full/folder:root/contents?v=3&alt=json
```

but now google docs api's are deprecated.can anyone please guideline How to acheive this using google apis now.

link reference : `https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#using_google_apps_administrative_access_to_impersonate_other_domain_users`

Answer (score 2):

With the new API's and OAuth 2 you can accomplish this functionality but for it you will have to use Service account with domain wide delegation.

Basically with the service account it would be possible to impersonate users in the domain and make API calls in user's behalf. For getting information about documents you will use the Drive API.

Here is the documentation on service account:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

And Drive API:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/

hope this helps.